# Euler circuits for the graph

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

How many different Euler circuits are there in the graph that begins at $A$ and then visits $D$ as the immediate next vertex?

My answer is $16$, and I suppose I have counted all possible such Euler circuits. I wonder whether I have missed additionally possible paths, and would be welcomed to know that. [image]

Comment: Does anyone have larger value instead of 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

Notice that such an Euler circuit must use $e_2$. So you can reduce the problem to finding the number of Euler *trails* starting at $C$ and ending at $A$ in $G - D$.

[image: The graph G minus D]

Think of an Euler trail in this case as a sequence of five edges $e_{i_1}e_{i_2}\cdots e_{i_5}$. Perhaps one of the easier ways to count is to single out an edge, say $e_3$, and count the number of valid sequences with $e_3$ in the first position, then the second, and so on. Since we are starting at $C$, you may notice that a sequence representing an Euler trail can only have $e_3$ in the first, third, and fifth position. You obtain

1. First: $4$ trails. Traverse $e_3$. There are $4$ ways to go from $A$ to $C$, back to $A$, that is two choices from $A$ to $B$, two choices from $B$ to $C$, and the way back is determined.
2. Third: $8$ trails. You can go $CBCABA$ of which there are four ways, or $CBACBA$, another four ways.
3. Fifth: $4$ trails, similar to the first case.

While this answer is long winded, at least in thinking this way you can be confident that you've exhausted all possibilities in your count. I believe in general it is hard ($NP$-hard?) to count the number of Euler circuits in a given undirected graph.

Comment: Genius! Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: @rasul_rza24 You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I think $16$ seems to be the correct value. I also counted and obtained $16$ as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I will also wait for others to see the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late, but you are correct. Another way to think about it is to consider the different starting paths you can take:

> $ C-B-A-B-C-A:$ You can choose $2$ out of the $4$ paths to go
> forward, and the remaining $2$ will be used to return to $C$. 
> Hence, $\binom{4}{2} = 6$

> $C-A-B-C-B-A:$ Going from $A-C,$ you can choose $2$ out of the $4$ paths,\
> so  $\binom{4}{2} = 6$

> $C-B-C-A-B-A:$ You can choose $1$ out of $2$ for $C-B,$ and $1$ out of $2$ for $B-A.$ Hence, $2 \cdot \binom{2}{1} = 4.$

$$\implies 6+6+4 = 16.$$

Comment: Please use MathJax to type math on this site please see [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) and [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)